# Hiding a div on a URL

Tags: html, css, url, browser, cross-browser

On a URL there is a `div` element to which I want to add the attribute `hidden`. What's the simplest (meaning "direct" or "low level", not "popular" or "common") way of doing this? The question is not about hacking a URL (although this would be a bonus), it's sufficient if my browser just hides the damn `div`. I know it should be doable w/ Tampermonkey but I'm not sure whether it makes sense to use it for such a (theoretically, at least) simple task. I'm using Chromium (v. >=53) but would prefer a cross-browser solution

Comment: If you want to apply JavaScript to a website you neither own not control then TamperMonkey, or GreaseMonkey, is the way to go. If you want to style certain elements then you may get away with using a user stylesheet, depending on whether your browser let's you apply a custom stylesheet to a specific site.

Comment: Choose your favorite ad blocker and mark that div as an ad.

Comment: I don't care if it's JavaScript, JQuery, TamperMonkey or something else as long as (you find) it's the simplest way. So I suggest you propose a method and write a more detailed answer. As to using an ad blocker, I didn't know you can block individual div-s, but since I'm managing ads w/ hosts file only, I don't want to install an ad blocker for this div